# What does 'value is a reference' mean for JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I was trying to understand passing of variables and objects in JavaScript, and came across [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language). 
It is explained that JavaScript objects are passed by value, but the value itself is a reference. Though I understood what was happening in the examples given on that page, I am still confused so as to why. Can anyone please explain what does "value itself is a reference" mean?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language?lq=1

Comment: @aquinas, The link that I have mentioned in my question is the same as the one you have stated. My question was in reference to that page, so I believe its not a duplicate! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some languages have a "pass by reference" concept for function arguments which means that when you call a function and pass in a variable *by reference* the function can modify the original variable to hold some other value - it has a reference to the original variable.

With "pass by value" when you call a function and pass in a variable the function only gets the value so can't change the original variable that was passed in.

JS only has "pass by value", however when you pass an object as a parameter the "value" is a reference to the original object such that the function can modify, create or delete properties of that object, but the function *can't* modify the original variable to refer to some other object or value.

Example:

```
function changeObj(someObj) {
    someObj.a = 1000;
    someObj.c = "test";

    someObj = { "x" : 5 };
    console.log(someObj);   // { "x" : 5 }
}

var o = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 };
changeObj(o);
console.log(o);   // { "a" : 1000, "b" : 2, "c" : "test" }
```

The code I've shown creates a variable, `o`, that references an object with `a` and `b` properties. It then calls the function `changeObj` and passes in `o`. The function changes the value of the `a` property and creates a new `c` property - the function is modifying the same object that variable `o` refers to because it has a reference to that object. But then the function assigns `someObj` equal to a completely new object. This does *not* affect `o` at all because the function only had a reference to the object `o` was pointing at, it didn't have access to the `o` variable itself.

Comment: You're welcome. I added an example that (I hope) makes it even more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Like Java, Python, and many other languages, in JavaScript, **objects are not values**.

What that means is that, when you evaluate an expression, the value you get from that is either a primitive or a reference (a reference is a pointer to an object). When you create an object, that expression evaluates to a reference. When you access a field of an object or call a method on an object, the thing on the left is a reference. Basically, anything you do with objects must be done through a reference to the object. There is no syntax for dealing with objects directly.

You cannot have a variable whose value "is" an object (unlike C++, where you can have both a variable whose value is an object, and a variable whose value is a pointer that points to an object); you can only have a variable whose value is a reference that points to an object.

This is apparent from the fact that when you assign a variable, a new object is never created. When you assign a reference, the assigned variable has a copy of the value of the original reference, and thus points to the same object as the original reference. There is nothing that you can put in a variable that causes assigning it to create a new object.

So if someone says "pass an object to a function", I say, No, you cannot pass an object, because objects are not values. You must be passing a reference to an object. Like in assignment, when you pass a reference, the value of it is copied. JavaScript is always pass-by-value.

Answer (score 1):

> It is explained that JavaScript objects are passed by value, but the value itself is a reference.

That's rather confusing wording. What they mean is that when objects are passed to functions, the reference value which points to the object is passed instead of the actual object.

Comment: ... and that reference is passed by value.

Comment: well, in that case, how is it different from the object just being passed by reference?

Comment: Think of an object reference like a license plate number. If I tell you the number of my car which you write on a piece of paper, you can find my car and drive it. If you change the number on the paper, it will reference a different car, but my car will retain its original number.